# undefined method 'edit_*_path' (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get the error: undefined method `edit_cycle_roads_path'

This is my index.html

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cycle_roads_path(cycle_roads) %></td>
```

And this is a routesr:

```
    resources :cycle_roads
```

If I run rake routes i get this:

```
    cycle_roads GET    /cycle_roads(.:format)          cycle_roads#index
                POST   /cycle_roads(.:format)          cycle_roads#create
 new_cycle_road GET    /cycle_roads/new(.:format)      cycle_roads#new
edit_cycle_road GET    /cycle_roads/:id/edit(.:format) cycle_roads#edit
     cycle_road GET    /cycle_roads/:id(.:format)      cycle_roads#show
                PATCH  /cycle_roads/:id(.:format)      cycle_roads#update
                PUT    /cycle_roads/:id(.:format)      cycle_roads#update
                DELETE /cycle_roads/:id(.:format)      cycle_roads#destroy
           root GET    /                               cycle_roads#index
```

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that you simply have to singularize your path:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cycle_road_path(cycle_roads) %></td>
```

And `cycle_roads` must be a single resource in this case, you should probably singularize it too.

Comment: Oh my god :D I didn't saw this. Thanks :)